# return true if value is in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a program that should connect to a php file on my website. In the C# they enter a value (password). The password would then be sent to the webpage (`example.com/example.php?param=<password>`)

I know how to make the program send the password but I don't know how to compare the value entered to a value in a table of my mysql database. If the value is in the database I want it to return true.

Comment: if your comparing raw password from user to raw password in db, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: What do you have so far? Please post it in the question.

Comment: Is it the SQL or the php that's giving you trouble?

Comment: Hash both passwords.  Compare the hashes..

Comment: You should be using a robust [crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) function in order to correctly hash your passwords. Storing plaintext passwords is almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

sql

```
    SELECT `password`
    FROM `tableName`
    WHERE `password` = :password
```

:password should be the value you are checking for in the database

Comment: Shouldn't those be backticks, and not single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

```
select 1 from your_table where password = 'thepass'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 where password = '$password'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows >0)
   return true;
return false;
```